# Getting Paypal to do an immediate redirect?

Tags: redirect, paypal

When the PayPal transaction is complete, PayPal shows this:

```
Thanks for your order
Your payment of $XXXX.XX USD is complete.
You're now going back to MYSITE.
If you are not redirected within 10 seconds, click here.
```

I don't want the client to even see this page. Is there any way to either avoid it completely, or set the redirect time to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will also need a Website Payments Pro subscription for that.
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/website-payments-pro

Once you have it, get the API signature, API username & API password from the My Profile area of your paypal account.

Then, use the Direct Payment method as described in the following manual
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WPP_IntegrationGuide.pdf

As mentioned by Watermark, you might need to review PCI requirements and at least have SSL on your site before you can do this.

Comment: So is thhere no way to just decrease this redirection time without going the IPN route?

Comment: Page 438-441 explains the options available to customizing the payment pages using payments standard.  Skipping this page isn't one. https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: Thanks man! :-) PayPal is probably going to be ditched quite soon.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://developer.paypal.com/. You can build your own interface using PayPal's API. The user will never know that PayPal handled the transaction.

Be sure to review PCI-DSS requirements when using this approach.

Answer (score -1):

What you ask is achievable with PayPal Payments Standard, but the seller account receiving the payment needs to be a PayPal Business/Premier account (a free upgrade), and they need to enable Auto Return and provide a Return URL in their PayPal account > Profile > Profile & Settings > My Selling Tools > Website Preferences.

You can also pass a `return` URL variable to checkout for each order, which would override any Return URL (or lack thereof) in the seller's PayPal account profile; however, if Auto Return is not also enabled in the seller's account, the buyer would need to click past the end of checkout manually in order to be redirected to that URL.