# Set the timeout return after paypal success

Tags: php, paypal

I have to wait 10 seconds after successful payment will therefore be redirect to the success of the website page of me. So I want after the payment is successful, it automatically to inform my page so I can update the order information

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOIbY.png)

Comment: The order isn't updated by the user coming back to your site unless you have configured it that way. Paypal will send you a response via your PHP script to let you know that the order went through.

Comment: Like what @Wicked has said, you may want to look into PayPal's [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

Comment: I have use Instant Payment Notification but until 10s this implement PayPal transactions. Help me

Comment: @Wicked, i have using IPN and attribute return but i still see 10s

Comment: The redirect has nothing to do with the IPN(Instant payment notification.) The redirect settings are set in paypal's settings. You log in -> Profile -> Selling Tools -> Website Payment Preferences. You will see the options to change a lot of the settings. Unfortunately you can not change the time. If you use paypal pro you can completely skip going to paypal and check out directly from your site.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked if it was possible to change the redirect time after his customers check out. (10 Seconds.) The conclusion based on my searching and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744676/getting-paypal-to-do-an-immediate-redirect) is that this is only possible with a Pro subscription.